# Search for specific Binary column in all tables in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to search where a binary field value is in all my database tables. I am following off from [this](https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Searching%20all%20columns%20in%20all%20tables%20in%20a%20database.aspx) code, which works great, but it is for only text type data types.

I am trying to search where the value of `SID_BINARY(N'S-1-4-20-45654656-564654656-4566786-12346')` is in all my tables.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Example code:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL=''

-- ------------------------------------------
-- Enter the string to be searched for here :
--
SET @SearchString = 'SID_BINARY(N''S-1-4-20-45654656-564654656-4566786-12346'')'
-- ------------------------------------------

SELECT   @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),COUNT(*)) + '' matches in column ''+'''
         + C.name + '''+'' on table '' + ''' + SC.name + '.' + T.name +
         ''' [Matches for '''+@SearchString+''':] FROM ' +
         QUOTENAME(SC.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.name) + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(C.name) +
         ' LIKE ''%' + @SearchString +
         '%'' HAVING COUNT(*)>0 UNION ALL ' +CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM     sys.columns C
JOIN     sys.tables T
ON       C.object_id=T.object_id
JOIN     sys.schemas SC
ON       SC.schema_id=T.schema_id
JOIN     sys.types ST
ON       C.user_type_id=ST.user_type_id
JOIN     sys.types SYST
ON       ST.system_type_id=SYST.user_type_id
AND      ST.system_type_id=SYST.system_type_id
WHERE    SYST.name IN ('varchar','nvarchar','text','ntext','char','nchar', 'varbinary', 'binary')
ORDER BY T.name, C.name

-- Strip off the last UNION ALL
IF LEN(@SQL)>12
  SELECT @SQL=LEFT(@SQL,LEN(@SQL)- 12)

EXEC(@SQL)

--PRINT @SQL
```

With that code I get the following error on every line:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'S'.
```

Comment: Just as a note: you *are* aware that SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Seems like it's easily enough the chaneg the `WHERE` and the input value (which should ***really*** be parametrised not injected!!!). Do you understand how the above works (injection,security risks, and all)?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I updated my code...